# How to pass Apex type to method from LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

## Problem Statement

I am trying to pass an instance of an `Apex` type from LWC into an `AuraEnabled` method. However, all of the attributes are coming through as `null`.

---

## MVR

#### Back End

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void doStuff(Model instance)
    {
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(instance));
        // { "sampleAttribute": null }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String sampleAttribute;
    }
}
```

#### Front End

```
import doStuff from "@salesforce/apex/MyController.doStuff"

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    ...
    const instance = {
        sampleAttribute: "I am populated"
    };
    console.debug(instance);
    // { sampleAttribute: "I am populated" }

    doStuff({ instance })
        .then(result => { ... })
        .catch(error => { ... });
}
```

---

## Question

**Why are my attributes all cleared out by the time they arrive at the back end?** They are clearly populated right before I send them. I even tried specifying each attribute via string key just to be sure that wasn't contributing to the problem, but it did not resolve the issue.

---

## Workaround

For now I am using serialization to get the call to work.

#### Back End

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void doStuff(String payload)
{
    doStuffWithModel((Model)JSON.deserialize(payload, Model.class));
}
public static void doStuffWithModel(Model instance)
{
    // implementation
}
```

#### Front End

```
const instance = {
    sampleAttribute: "I am populated"
};
doStuff({ instance })
    .then(result => { ... })
    .catch(error => { ... });
```

> Expose Apex Methods to Lightning Web Components
>   To expose an Apex method to a Lightning web component, the method must be static and either global or public. Annotate the method with @AuraEnabled.
>
> ...
>
> These types are supported for input and output.
>
> - [Primitive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_basic.htm)—Boolean, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Double, Integer, Long, and String.
> - [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_object_salesforce.htm)—standard and custom sObjects are both supported.
> - [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm#ref_attr_types_apex)—an instance of an Apex class. (Most often a custom class.)
> - [Collection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm)—a collection of any of the other types.

But the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex) clearly indicates use of Apex types is supported. Using JSON should not be necessary.

Comment: I think NULL is actually expected behavior here. We are venturing into the "pass by reference by value" behavior of Apex (i.e. Java bytecode). https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html

Comment: That article doesn't mention pass-by-reference between front-end and back-end. That sounds infeasible at best. I do not think it has any bearing on the observed behavior.

Comment: This *should* work. Oddly, trying to repro this issue gives me an internal server error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This fails because the Model class is an inner class. It is probably a bug, but we hit this a while back and found:

- instances of inner classes can be returned to the client but cannot be passed to the server
- instances of top level classes can be passed both ways

As per sfdcfox's comment, we most often saw an internal server error when trying to pass an instance of an inner class to an aura enabled method.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm#ref_attr_types_apex) does say:

> Custom classes used for component attributes shouldn’t be inner classes or use inheritance. While these Apex language features might work in some situations, there are known issues, and their use is unsupported in all cases.

Whilst this appears to be for Aura code, the [LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex) indicates LWC has the same behaviour (see the link for "Apex" in the section entitled "Expose Apex Methods to Lightning Web Components"). So whilst it is probably a bug, they have documented to say things *can* go wrong if you try to use inner classes.

Something else that can cause issues is the use of @AuraEnabled public attributes in your data object, which can be remedied by switching to public properties. This **MAY** allow you to keep the class as an inner class, but there's no guarantee this will work in all cases. Certainly changing your inner Model class to a top level one like the following will resolve any issues:

```
public class Model {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String someAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I found the same with your first bullet. Man that's kind of mind blowing. I would agree that's got to be a bug.

Comment: Quite bizarre and very annoying.

Comment: I mean that sounds like a relic from Visualforce days...I remember the same constraint for parameters on a component (not page)...

Comment: We hoisted our classes to be top-level where necessary, but your solution of JSON serialize/deserialize does at least allow for a less cluttered source tree. Maybe we should have done that :D

Comment: I prefer avoiding it. Maybe I'll regret that decision in a year. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: All my attributes are still null. :(

Comment: @AdrianLarson got it by creating Model class separately, you might be missing something else

Comment: One other thing of note - the documentation expresses all @AuraEnabled apex class values as public properties rather than public attributes. Try changing that?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are getting at. Are you saying to add `{ get; set; }`? I think I read somewhere today that those aren't supported.

Comment: I do mean update Model to have ```@AuraEnabled public String sampleAttribute { get; set; }```. Again, we found that use of a public attribute does generally work but there were a few edge cases resolved by making it a property, to align with [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm#ref_attr_types_apex). Note that this is the documentation linked from the [LWC docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick...

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: FYI at least for me inner classes work fine once I add accessors.

Comment: Adding { get; set; } for inner class attributes did the tirck here as well!